# How to use global variables and how to define them properly?

Tags: python, for-loop, global-variables, return-value

I'm stuck on this one which contains global variables and I know that, the way how I crated them, it just doesn't work. Let me show you my code:

```
suffix_map = {}
prefix = ()

def markov_body(file, order, header_text, header = True):
    start = open(file)
    if header:
        for line in start:
            if line.startswith(header_text):
                break

    for line in start:      
        for word in line.rstrip().split():
            global prefix
            if len(prefix) < order:
                prefix += (word,)
                return
            try:
                suffix_map[prefix].append(word)
            except KeyError:
                suffix_map[prefix] = [word]

            prefix = shifted(prefix, word)

def shifted(t, word):
    return t[1:] + (word,)

def markov_text(n):
    begin = random.choice(list(suffix_map.keys()))
    for i in range(n):
        suff = suffix_map.get(begin)
        if suff == None:
            return markov_text(n-i)

        word = random.choice(suff)
        print(word, end = "")
        begin = shifted(begin, word)

print(markov_text(100))
```

The `global` variables are `prefix` and `suffix_map`. The first question would be why do I have to define it again as `global` in my for-loop if it's global and defined outside the method? The second question is: why does not add anything at all to `prefix` and `suffix_map`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: side comment: global variables are bad programming. i wouldn't use them. why don't you add `prefix` as argument to your function?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `global suffix_map` and `global prefix`.